# Programmatically pass arguments to grunt task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have a grunt task that calls other grunt tasks. I want to call a subtask with programmatically determined arguments. Is this possible? I spent some time digging around the **lib/grunt.js** and **lib/grunt/task.js**, but couldn't figure it out.

I'm using `grunt-compass` with the following arguments specified in **Gruntfile.js**:

```
compass: {
  default_options: {
    src: 'components/201',
    dest: 'build',
    require: ['zurb-foundation']
  }
}
```

I want to be able to override them at runtime:

**tasks/my-task.js**:

```
// simplified example
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask('foo', 'bar', function() {
    var chooseDest = doWork();
    grunt.task.run('compass', {src: 'src', dest: chooseDest});
  });
};
```

For reference:

```
$ grunt --version
grunt-cli v0.1.6
grunt v0.4.0rc6
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I figured it out. Use the `<%= %>` syntax in Gruntfile.js:

```
compass: {
  default_options: {
    src: 'components/<%= myTask.src %>',
    dest: 'build',
    require: ['zurb-foundation']
  }
}
```

Then you can set it in your task:

```
grunt.config.set('myTask.src', getSrc());
```

Comment: Where do you get that myTask var? is it global? is it defined on grunt .iniConfig?

Comment: @DanRocha I would guess it is a variable specified in the grunt.initConfig which you set during runtime using the last line of code that Rosarch posted.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit all the Grunt config:

```
grunt.config('compass.default_options.src', 'blabla');
```

Just before run the task. But your solution is "cleaner".