# Programmatically set options for grunt task?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a grunt task that looks at options with `grunt.option('foo')`. If I'm calling this task from `grunt.task.run('my-task')`, how can I change those arguments?

I'm looking for something like:

```
grunt.task.run('my-task', {foo: 'bar'});
```

which would be the equivalent of:

```
$ grunt my-task --foo 'bar'
```

Is this possible?

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780622/programmatically-pass-arguments-to-grunt-task) is another issue I ran in to but is not exactly the same, because in this case I don't have access to the original task's Gruntfile.js.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like I can use the following:

```
grunt.option('foo', 'bar');
grunt.task.run('my-task');
```

It feels a bit odd to set the options globally instead of just for that command, but it works.

Comment: It will not work if you need to run 2 or more tasks :/ if you have a loop and set `grunt.option` and `grunt.task.run`, both tasks will run with the last iterate of `grunt.option`; @Rosarch, did u know how to solve it?

Comment: @RafaelVerger you can create two tasks, one that runs the task and one that changes the option.  Queue up the tasks in alternating order and they will get run with the option set correctly.

Comment: It works if you have a limited set of options; but when you get those options dynamically (like querying a service discover for servers with MySQL) it will not work

Comment: @RafaelVerger You can queue up arg lists in a global array then .shift() your way through them. Insanely ugly, but that seems to be common with Grunt.

Answer (score 20):

If you can use task-based config options instead of grunt.option, this should work to give you more granular control:

```
grunt.config.set('task.options.foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 7):

Create a new task which set the option, then call the modified task. This is a real life example with [assemble](http://assemble.io):

```
grunt.registerTask('build_prod', 'Build with production options', function () {
  grunt.config.set('assemble.options.production', true);
  grunt.task.run('build');
});
```

Comment: This is the correct way to achieve the desired functionality.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Alessandro Pezzato

Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean:dist', 'assemble', 'compass:dist', 'cssmin', 'copy:main']);

    grunt.registerTask('build-prod', 'Build with production options', function () {
        grunt.config.set('assemble.options.production', true);
        grunt.task.run('build');
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build-live', 'Build with production options', function () {
        grunt.option('assemble.options.production', false);
        grunt.task.run('build');
    });
```

Now you can run

`$ grunt build-prod`

-OR-

`$ grunt build-live`

They will both do the full task 'build' and respectively pass a value to one of the [options of assemble](http://assemble.io/docs/Options.html), namely production 'true' or 'false'.

---

In addition to illustrate the assemble example a bit more:

In assemble you have the option to add a `{{#if production}}do this on production{{else}}do this not non production{{/if}}`

Comment: This is great. You can also define which tasks are run in the different options by passing the taskList directly to the run command (for example, another build-dev command that could skip clean and cssmin) :

grunt.task.run( ['clean:dist', 'assemble', 'compass:dist', 'cssmin', 'copy:main']);

Answer (score 1):

grunt is all programmatic.. so if you have set options on tasks before, you have done this programmatically.

just use `grunt.initConfig({ ... })` to set options for tasks.

and if you already initialized, and need to change configuration afterwards, you can do something like

`grunt.config.data.my_plugin.goal.options = {};`

I am using it for my project and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran up against this same issue: programmatically setting grunt options and running tasks multiple times from within a single parent task. As @Raphael Verger mentions, this is not possible, as `grunt.task.run` defers the running of the task until the current task is finished:

```
grunt.option('color', 'red');
grunt.task.run(['logColor']);
grunt.option('color', 'blue');
grunt.task.run(['logColor']);
```

Will result in the color *blue* being logged twice.

After some fiddling, I came up with a grunt task that allows dynamically specifying a different option/config for each sub-task to be run. I've published the task as [grunt-galvanize](https://github.com/dylancwood/grunt-galvanize). Here's how it works:

```
var galvanizeConfig = [
  {options: {color: 'red'}, configs: {}},
  {options: {color: 'blue'}, configs: {}}
];
grunt.option('galvanizeConfig', galvanizeConfig);
grunt.task.run(['galvanize:log']);
```

This will log *red* then *blue*, as desired by running the *log* task with each of the options/configs specified in `galvanizeConfig`.