# Grunt task target array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, gruntjs, build-process

I can set multiple arrays of files to a target:

```
task:{
    target:{
        files:[
            {
                expand:true,
                cwd:'client/',
                dest:'server/',
                src:[
                    'scripts/**/*.js',
                    'styles/**/*.css',
                    'images/**'
                ]
            },
            {
                expand:true,
                cwd:'client/assets/',
                src:'**/*',
                dest:'server/'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I want to do the same with a target.

Like this:

```
task:{
    server:[
        {
            options:{
                …
            },
            files:{
                …
            }
        },
        {
            options:{
                …
            },
            files:{
                …
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But this does not work with Grunt:

```
Warning: Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf' Use --force to continue.
```

How can I do it?

Now I use this scheme to do the same:

```
task:{
    server_<subtask_one>:{
        options:{
            …
        },
        files:{
            …
        }
    },
    server_<subtask_second>:{
        options:{
            …
        },
        files:{
            …
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not handy to repeat task prefix to each subtask and then launch them into separate lines like this:

```
'dataSeparator:<target>_<subtask_one>',
'dataSeparator:<target>_<subtask_second>',
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to write a custom task this is your only option. But most tasks do allow you to specify an `options` block at the task level, so you can at least save yourself some repetition:

```
task:{
    options:{
        // options common to all tasks
    },
    server_<subtask_one>:{
        options:{
            // override options if necessary
        },
        files:{
            // custom for this target
        }
    },
    server_<subtask_second>:{
        options:{
            // override options if necessary
        },
        files:{
            // custom for this target
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, you might be able write a custom task to dynamically reset the [grunt config options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863959/programmatically-set-options-for-grunt-task) per target, but this is messy and I would not advise it... not even sure it would work properly.

```
grunt.registerTask('mutli-task', 'Compile options and pass to task', function() {

    grunt.config.set('task.server_<subtask_one>.some_setting', 'value');
    // ...
    grunt.task.run('task');

    // Now do it again, but with different settings... maybe in a loop?
});
```